# Accessing IMEI # From Web Application

Tags: asp.net

Is there any possibility that can i get the IMEI # Of Mobile from a web application. Suppose a request comes from a mobile then i can get the imei # from that request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is... **NO**
through web app its not possible to get IMEI of phone.

however you can build a native app to get the IMEI 
e.g. android java, symbian c++, j2me etc.

regards,
NJ