# How to get imei using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, mobile

I have a mobile ready web application, the thing is that I need the imei to allow only users that is registered only on the database to use the application. Is there any way to get imei on devices without using any .dll?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @TimSchmelter I want it on the page load it automatically detect the imei of the mobile device, scan imei. But I don't know how to get the imei...

Comment: No this is not possible. Allowing web pages to access the IMEI is seen as a security risk so is not allowed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing IMEI # From Web Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629900/accessing-imei-from-web-application)